# Open PDF in LibreOffice without (bad) OCR text

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

Whenever I open a PDF in LibreOffice Draw, it opens the PDF and adds some (bad) OCR text on top of it, making the document unreadable. I have to spend a long time selecting the text and deleting it, or else select each page's image and copy and paste it into a new file, in order to get rid of the (bad and unreadable) OCR text.

I also tried [opening it directly in LibreOffice Writer](https://superuser.com/questions/1259704/how-can-i-open-pdf-files-in-libreoffice-writer-rather-than-draw) but it has the same problem.

Can this "feature" be disabled? This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/libreoffice/comments/ig0rjt/opening_a_pdf_automatically_adds_bad_ocr_text_to/) has the same problem without a good solution.

Comment: This is most likely not a Draw problem - the PDF file already contains the OCR layer. This happens when scanning a document before creating a PDF, the option is enabled in the scanning program, something like "Create a PDF file that supports keyword searches"

Comment: Open the PDF file in a PDF viewer to see if the text layer is part of the PDF file.

Comment: The PDF opens and prints fine in Chrome and in Adobe Reader. The garbage is only visible when the PDF is opened in LibreOffice.